# (Python) how to grab text from a dynamic webpage that is already opened in a firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, python, html

There is a dynamic webpage that I have opened with Firefox browser and that I leave running the entire work day while of course continuing using the computer ... I'm relatively new to Python and have been searching for a solution for the past couple of days all over the web but can't seem to find anything that works ; I've tried playing with BeautifulSoup, requests, nltk, urllib.request, webbrowser, etc.
I'd like this action of periodically checking this dynamic webpage , checking every 5 seconds , and grab the visible text on the webpage , and insert it into a text file , and from there in the text file search for specific words and act upon them whenever they are present.

Comment: Does the page needs to be open ? If it's available on an internet server, you could directly retrieve the content trough an HTTP request.

Comment: page is already open ..... the url looks like this: http://usaaviatfpsbifin001abg.okbi.hucs.imt/desktop/container/?locale=en_US#home ..... it's mainly javascript running on this page ..... it's a Cisco Finesse webpage for setting your phone system status to available or not , it is always almost signing me out , so I need a way to note when it does it ....

Comment: from further looking at the url & webpage content , I found this: <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="permaLinkViewer" src="/cuic/permalink/report/reportviewer/ReportViewer.htmx?reportId=9347816B1000014E61B060505....... seems like it's some type of report , wondering if there is other way to get this ......this url works only if I am connected to VPN ,,,, if VPN disconnects then I lose connection to this phone system ..... but I've noticed the issue is with this Cisco Finees webpage , because many a times I get signed off even if my VPN is up and running ..... so I've tried doing ping test

Comment: .... so I've tried doing ping test , but that isn't valid because I will still get responses from the box "usaaviatfpsbifin001abg.okbi.hucs.imt" , despite being signed out of the webpage . . . I'm interested in this suggestion about HTTP request but don't know how to go about it . . .

Comment: Hum, if the content heavily uses JS, simple requests won't to the work :/ I'm not entirely sure about how one would interface with a browser with python due to all the sandboxing. The "easiest" way seems to make a quick browser plugin (a userscript should be enough) that would scan the page and send it via xhr to a an app listening to a port on your computer.